# Weird camera bug in Raylib

Tags: c, raylib

So I was working on adding a simple "floor" (basically code that keeps the camera from going below a certain level) and jumping when I encountered a bug that made my camera slowly look down, even though my code didn't have anything to do with camera.target. Some times will dip down to a y value of maybe 1.999... if anyone has a better solution than setting a depth limit, please let me know. Here is the code that deals with preventing the camera from falling, and jumping. if anyone needs all of the code, I will be happy to provide it.

```
if (IsKeyDown(KEY_SPACE)) {
       if (camera.position.y <= 2.0f) {
             yMomentum = yMomentum + speed;
       }
}
```

```
// forces camera to be above 0
if (camera.position.y < 2.0f) {
    camera.position.y = 2.0f;
    yMomentum = 0;
}
```

edit. here is all the code if needed:

```
#include "raylib.h"
#include "rcamera.h"

#define MAX_COLUMNS 20

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Program main entry point
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(void)
{
    // Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const int screenWidth = 1280;
    const int screenHeight = 720;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib [core] example - 3d camera first person");

    // Define the camera to look into our 3d world (position, target, up vector)
    Camera camera = { 0 };
    camera.position = (Vector3){ 0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f };    // Camera position
    camera.target = (Vector3){ 1.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f };      // Camera looking at point
    camera.up = (Vector3){ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };          // Camera up vector (rotation towards target)
    camera.fovy = 85.0f;                                // Camera field-of-view Y
    camera.projection = CAMERA_PERSPECTIVE;             // Camera projection type
    float yMomentum = 0.0f;
    int cameraMode = CAMERA_FIRST_PERSON;


    DisableCursor();                    // Limit cursor to relative movement inside the window
    void input(float xMomentum);
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Main game loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose())        // Detect window close button or ESC key
    {
     


        // Update camera computes movement internally depending on the camera mode
        // Some default standard keyboard/mouse inputs are hardcoded to simplify use
        // For advance camera controls, it's recommended to compute camera movement manually

        UpdateCameraPro(&camera,
            (Vector3) {
                0.0f,   // Move forward-backward
                0.0f,   // Move right-left
                yMomentum       // Move up-down
        },
            (Vector3) {
            GetMouseDelta().x * 0.05f,                          // Rotation: yaw
                GetMouseDelta().y * 0.05f,                          // Rotation: pitch
                0.0f                                                // Rotation: roll
        },
                0.0f);                              // Move to target (zoom)

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Draw
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        BeginDrawing();

        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

        BeginMode3D(camera);

        DrawPlane((Vector3) { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }, (Vector2) { 32.0f, 32.0f }, LIGHTGRAY); // Draw ground
        DrawCube((Vector3) { -16.0f, 2.5f, 0.0f }, 1.0f, 5.0f, 32.0f, BLUE);    // Draw a blue wall
        DrawCube((Vector3) { 16.0f, 2.5f, 0.0f }, 1.0f, 5.0f, 32.0f, LIME);     // Draw a green wall
        DrawCube((Vector3) { 0.0f, 2.5f, 16.0f }, 32.0f, 5.0f, 1.0f, GOLD);     // Draw a yellow wall


        EndMode3D();

        // Draw info boxes



        EndDrawing();


        yMomentum = yMomentum - 0.001f;
        // forces camera to be above 0
        if (camera.position.y < 2.0f) {
            camera.position.y = 2.0f;
            yMomentum = 0;
        }
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    // De-Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CloseWindow();      // Close window and OpenGL context
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more context about the 'yMomentum' variable and how it is used in your code?

Comment: Earlier in the program just increases momentum if I jump, and decreases it due to gravity. this function in the program sets yMomentum because you don't keep going through a floor if you jump and then land on the floor (basically it prevents the camera from clipping through the 'ground').

Answer (score 1):

The first thing of note is that, unlike the [example](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/examples/core/core_3d_camera_first_person.c) (which I assume this to be a modification of), you are not calling `SetTargetFPS`, so your frame rate is unbound (and extremely variable).

Adding back `SetTargetFPS(60)` (or even a value of say 10), and the debug code from the example

```
DrawText(TextFormat("- Position: (%06.3f, %06.3f, %06.3f)", camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z), 610, 60, 10, BLACK);
DrawText(TextFormat("- Target: (%06.3f, %06.3f, %06.3f)", camera.target.x, camera.target.y, camera.target.z), 610, 75, 10, BLACK);
DrawText(TextFormat("- Up: (%06.3f, %06.3f, %06.3f)", camera.up.x, camera.up.y, camera.up.z), 610, 90, 10, BLACK);
```

helps to highlight the primary issue in a human-observable way.

---

Note that the vectors passed to `UpdateCameraPro` represent the *amount of change* that should take place (deltas). When using `UpdateCameraPro`, [changing the Y-position of the camera changes the Y-target by the same amount](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/rcamera.h#L270).

The core issue is that when `camera.position.y == 2.0f`, `yMomentum` will be `-0.001f` on the *next* frame. On that next frame, the Y-position of the camera changes to `1.999f` via `UpdateCameraPro`, which causes the Y-target to shift as well.

Later during that *next* frame, `camera.position.y` will be `< 2.0f`, which causes it to be manually reset to `2.0f` (which does not shift the Y-target), and `yMomentum` will be reset to `0.0f`.

Then on the *frame after that*, the cycle starts again when `camera.position.y == 2.0f`.

In effect, you are ping-ponging between a Y-position of `2.0f` and `1.999f`, and *every* change in this value causes the Y-target to change in a single direction, causing it to shift down.

(*What is unclear to me is why this behaviour ever *stops*. Something to do with the way `UpdateCameraPro` adjusts/clamps the pitch, pitch affecting position [or vice versa], or rounding errors?*)

Some basic advice would be to calculate how much *change* you want to occur during the frame, detecting if that change would put the camera in an invalid position, making any adjustments *before* calling `UpdateCameraPro`.

A very cursory example (press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to instantly "jump"):

```
#include "raylib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    InitWindow(1280, 720, "raylib [core] example - 3d camera first person");

    Camera camera = {
        .position = (Vector3) { 0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f },
        .target = (Vector3) { 1.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f },
        .up = (Vector3) { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
        .fovy = 85.0f,
        .projection = CAMERA_PERSPECTIVE
    };

    SetTargetFPS(60);
    DisableCursor();

    const float GROUND = 2.0f;
    const float GRAVITY = -0.05f;
    const float JUMP_HEIGHT = 1.0f;

    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        float yChange = (IsKeyPressed(KEY_SPACE) && camera.position.y < (GROUND + 0.1f)) * JUMP_HEIGHT + GRAVITY;

        if (camera.position.y + yChange < GROUND)
            yChange = GROUND - camera.position.y;

        Vector2 md = GetMouseDelta();

        UpdateCameraPro(&camera,
                /* { forward-backward, left-right, up-down } */ (Vector3) { 0.0f, 0.0f, yChange },
                /* { yaw, pitch, roll } */ (Vector3) { md.x * 0.05f, md.y * 0.05f, 0.0f },
                /* zoom */ 0.0f);

        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

        BeginMode3D(camera);

        DrawPlane((Vector3) { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }, (Vector2) { 32.0f, 32.0f }, LIGHTGRAY);
        DrawCube((Vector3) { -16.0f, 2.5f, 0.0f }, 1.0f, 5.0f, 32.0f, BLUE);
        DrawCube((Vector3) { 16.0f, 2.5f, 0.0f }, 1.0f, 5.0f, 32.0f, LIME);
        DrawCube((Vector3) { 0.0f, 2.5f, 16.0f }, 32.0f, 5.0f, 1.0f, GOLD);

        EndMode3D();

        DrawText(TextFormat("- Position: (%06.12f, %06.12f, %06.12f)", camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z), 610, 60, 10, BLACK);
        DrawText(TextFormat("- Target: (%06.3f, %06.3f, %06.3f)", camera.target.x, camera.target.y, camera.target.z), 610, 75, 10, BLACK);
        DrawText(TextFormat("- Up: (%06.3f, %06.3f, %06.3f)", camera.up.x, camera.up.y, camera.up.z), 610, 90, 10, BLACK);
        DrawText(TextFormat("- Delta: (%06.3f, %06.3f)", md.x, md.y), 610, 105, 10, BLACK);
        DrawFPS(10, 10);

        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
}
```